# Intermediate Books/Resources about Best Practice and Idiomatic Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for a book in the vein of [Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) which, while not being targeted at the ruby beginner, gives a great overview of what 'grown up' idiomatic ruby code looks like, and gives great examples of how people might use the powers of the language. I found that the book almost perfectly mirrored what the experienced real world rubyists were writing.

I've settled quite comfortably now into obj-c, but I'd love to read a book like this that would take me from competent to enlightened. Are there any books/resources that might achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this book: [Programming in Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321711394)
I only have read some sections from it, but I think it mets your requirements, has a lot of helpful code and easy to follow tutorials and it's targeted to beginners and experienced programmers. As you can confirm in the book description:

> The book makes no assumptions about prior experience with object-oriented programming languages or with the C language (which Objective-C is based upon). Because of this, both beginners and experienced programmers alike can use this book to quickly and effectively learn the fundamentals of Objective-C. Readers can also learn the concepts of object-oriented programming without having to first learn all of the intricacies of the underlying procedural language (C).

Comment: I'm looking into it, will give you the tick if it's what I'm looking for. Thanks!